# Text Boxes side by side with Read more buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm quite new to writing codes(about a few weeks) and i've hit a wall while writing codes for my website. I want to have a layout such as this

Please visit here  https://ibb.co/wYkV8XS with div may be side by side and having button like read more and read less.

but can't figure out how to put two boxes side by side and having buttons with read more and read less. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want somethink like this?(try on full page)

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let b = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    b[i].classList.toggle("toggle");
})
}
```

```css
container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
}

container div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.card{
  width:25%;
  height:max-content;
  border:2px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
}

.card span{
  text-align:left;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 10;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.card.toggle span{
  -webkit-line-clamp: unset;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div>
<p class="card"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum finibus dolor quis pellentesque. Phasellus tincidunt elit et tellus auctor tincidunt. Fusce luctus quam ut dolor semper, in mattis orci varius. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi et lectus a nisl sodales dignissim. Suspendisse ornare eget nulla a porta. Donec at nisl eleifend, ultricies turpis rhoncus, vestibulum lacus. Proin nec erat erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod, lacus eget consectetur finibus, sem dui eleifend magna, ut accumsan velit nulla nec mi. Curabitur dictum sagittis massa a condimentum. Aenean egestas turpis ut dolor convallis aliquam. Donec rhoncus enim sit amet odio molestie, porttitor tempus risus viverra.</span>
  <button>READ MORE</button></p>

<p class="card"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum finibus dolor quis pellentesque. Phasellus tincidunt elit et tellus auctor tincidunt. Fusce luctus quam ut dolor semper, in mattis orci varius. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi et lectus a nisl sodales dignissim. Suspendisse ornare eget nulla a porta. Donec at nisl eleifend, ultricies turpis rhoncus, vestibulum lacus. Proin nec erat erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod, lacus eget consectetur finibus, sem dui eleifend magna, ut accumsan velit nulla nec mi. Curabitur dictum sagittis massa a condimentum. Aenean egestas turpis ut dolor convallis aliquam. Donec rhoncus enim sit amet odio molestie, porttitor tempus risus viverra.</span>
  <button>READ MORE</button></p>
  </div>

<div>
  <p class="card"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum finibus dolor quis pellentesque. Phasellus tincidunt elit et tellus auctor tincidunt. Fusce luctus quam ut dolor semper, in mattis orci varius. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi et lectus a nisl sodales dignissim. Suspendisse ornare eget nulla a porta. Donec at nisl eleifend, ultricies turpis rhoncus, vestibulum lacus. Proin nec erat erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod, lacus eget consectetur finibus, sem dui eleifend magna, ut accumsan velit nulla nec mi. Curabitur dictum sagittis massa a condimentum. Aenean egestas turpis ut dolor convallis aliquam. Donec rhoncus enim sit amet odio molestie, porttitor tempus risus viverra.</span>
  <button>READ MORE</button></p>
  
  <p class="card"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum finibus dolor quis pellentesque. Phasellus tincidunt elit et tellus auctor tincidunt. Fusce luctus quam ut dolor semper, in mattis orci varius. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi et lectus a nisl sodales dignissim. Suspendisse ornare eget nulla a porta. Donec at nisl eleifend, ultricies turpis rhoncus, vestibulum lacus. Proin nec erat erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod, lacus eget consectetur finibus, sem dui eleifend magna, ut accumsan velit nulla nec mi. Curabitur dictum sagittis massa a condimentum. Aenean egestas turpis ut dolor convallis aliquam. Donec rhoncus enim sit amet odio molestie, porttitor tempus risus viverra.</span>
  <button>READ MORE</button></p>
  </div>
  </container>
```